# how can I get value from json after I convert it into scala?

Tags: scala, jackson-databind

I have a json format data

```
{
  "featureList": {
    "whitelist-1": {
      "description": "whitelist 1",
      "whitelistedIdWithReasons": [
        {
          "accountIdRuleName": "611319436983:bud_connection_state",
          "reason": "bud_connection_state is a bad rule"
        },
        {
          "accountIdRuleName": "116958421622:PublishToDynamo",
          "reason": "PublishToDynamo is a bad rule"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanna convert it into scala, I have a ADT template like this

```
case class FeatureWhitelistingConfig(
     @JsonProperty("featureList") featureList: java.util.Map[String, Feature]
 )

 case class Feature(
     @JsonProperty("description") description: String,
     @JsonProperty("whitelistedIdWithReasons") whitelistedIdWithReasons: java.util.List[
       WhiteListedIdWithReason
     ]
 )

 case class WhiteListedIdWithReason(
     @JsonProperty("accountIdRuleName") accountIdRuleName: String,
     @JsonProperty("reason") reason: String
 )
```

how can I get "accountIdRuleName" from that? featureList.get("whitelist-1"), what should do next?

Comment: Firstly, I recommend using ```circe``` for handling JSON in Scala https://circe.github.io/circe/. Second, why are you using Java Lists and Java Maps ?

Comment: Hi, sinanspd the reason for all your question is, my partners already had their way to handling json in scala, and scala's map or list is abstract which I cant use that.

Comment: I would recommend you to use spray json or gson library it's really easy to use you can just convert json into case class and then access the fields